# How can I access List<KeyValuePair<string,int>> from MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am storing in MongoDB records with the following definition:

```
public class StorageRecord
{
    public int GrId { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<string,int>> Data { get; set; }
}
```

and sample like this one below:

```
var storageRecord = new StorageRecord
{
GrId = 12,
Data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>()
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>("xx", 12),
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>("yy", 13),
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>("zz", 14)
    }
}
```

Please tell me how should I write the query to retrive the `Sum` of all of the records which has for example `xx` key in the `Data` list of `KeyValuePair`.

I have started with the following statement but don't know what should be next:

```
var TotalXX = collection
            .Where(r => r.GrId == grId)
            .GroupBy(t => t.GrId)
            .Select(v => v.Select(c => c.Data));
```

Comment: On a side note, isn't `List<KeyValuePair<>>` the same as `Dictionary<>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need the `GroupBy`:

```
var TotalXX = collection
   .Where(storage => storage.GrId == grId)
   .Sum(storage => storage.Data.Count(kv => kv.Key == "xx"));
```

Comment: Yeah great, big thanks and yes it is working even without `GroupBy`

Comment: Additional question, what if I would like to sum up the values for specific key in all of the records?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk: i don't understand, remove the `Where` and change the `Count` accordingly...maybe

Comment: I mean smth like: TotalXX = collection
   .Where(storage => storage.GrId == grId)
   .Sum(storage => storage.Data.Value).Where(storage => storage.Data.Key == "xx");

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk: `collection.Where(s => s.GrId == grId).Sum(s => s.Data.Where(kv => kv.Key == "xx").Sum(kv => kv.Value))`